# My code gives me and error called "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=PROMOD-PC;Initial Catalog=travel_Directions;Integrated Security=True";

    String Strt_Address = TextBox1.Text;
    String End_Address = TextBox2.Text;

    String filePath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
    String filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    String ExtStr = Path.GetExtension(filename);
    String contenttype = String.Empty;

    switch (ExtStr)
    {
        case ".png":
            contenttype = "image/png";
            break;

        case ".jpg":
            contenttype = "image/jpg";
            break;

        case ".gif":
            contenttype = "image/gif";
            break;
    }

    if (contenttype != string.Empty)
    {
        Stream Strmf = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(Strmf);
        Byte[] imgbytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)Strmf.Length);


        //SqlDataReader sqldread = new SqlDataReader();

        String selQuery = "SELECT Id FROM MapDataImage WHERE Source='" + TextBox1.Text + "';";
        {

            SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand(selQuery, conn);

            conn.Open();

            SqlDataReader sqldread = scmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (sqldread.Read())
            {
                int Dbid = (int)sqldread["Id"];
                //string DbId = sqldread.GetInt32("Id").ToString();

                Label4.Text = Convert.ToString(Dbid);

                String QueryStr = "INSERT INTO User_Images(Id,Image) VALUES ('" + Dbid + "',@Image)";
                SqlCommand scmd1 = new SqlCommand(QueryStr, conn);
                scmd1.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = imgbytes;
                scmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }


            //String QueryStr = "UPDATE MapDataImage SET Image = @Image WHERE Source='" + TextBox1.Text + "';";
            //SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand(QueryStr, conn);
            //scmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = imgbytes;
            sqldread.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }
 }
```

first if condition will convert to bytes which i uploaded file through the file upload control.

Select command will check  the user textbox input name equals with database value
..
if it's equal the code will get the id from that table and store it as a int variable.

my uploaded image and that id will goes to another table.

my first SQL table =

```
Id = int
Source = varchar(max)
```

my second SQL data table =

```
image_id = int (primary key) Auto increment
Id = int (first table id store in here)
image = (varbinary)MAX
```

scenario is....
ex- think Facebook, if Facebook account name is valid, we can upload unlimited photos.
so situation is same here. if my name is equal with data base it will retrieve its id and under that id it will insert the images to second data table

when i want to retrieve those images. i can use for loop retrieve the images from second table.. yeah?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a new connection instead in the sqldread.Read()

```
SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection();
conn2.ConnectionString = ""; //your connection string
SqlCommand scmd1 = new SqlCommand(QueryStr, conn2);
scmd1.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = imgbytes;
conn2.Open();
scmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn2.Close();
```

Comment: It is not the connection object that is the problem, but rather the `SqlDataReader` that is mid-stream when he tries to attach another `SqlCommand` object.

Comment: but if he uses another sqlcommand object which would be associated with another sqlconnection it wouldnt interfere, which means another command executed in another connection wouldnt interfere with a command(sqlreader) being executed

Answer (score 0):

You can not reuse the connection in the loop while you are still reading from the SqlDataReader. 
Two options:

- Read all the ids and save them in a temporary list. Then loop through with this list.
- Create a new connection to do the image insert.

Comment: While creating a new connection would work, it is overkill, because it is not the connection object that is the problem, but rather the `SqlDataReader` that is mid-stream when he tries to attach another `SqlCommand` object.

Comment: @Karl, database connections are retrieved from the connection pool, so as long you properly dispose/close the SqlConnection object, it should be fine to create new SqlConnection objects in a loop. Anyway, I suggested to create a new connection, that can be done outside the loop. But, yes, in this case two connections will be used instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the `SqlDataReader` object right after you get the `Id` value from the database and re-associate the reader with the next command object, like this:

```
while (sqldread.Read())
{
     int Dbid = (int)sqldread["Id"];
}

sqldread.Close();

Label4.Text = Convert.ToString(Dbid);

String QueryStr = "INSERT INTO User_Images(Id,Image) VALUES ('" + Dbid + "',@Image)";
SqlCommand scmd1 = new SqlCommand(QueryStr, conn);
scmd1.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = imgbytes;

SqlDataReader sqldread = scmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Note: You should also look into the `using` statement, which allows for the database connection to be correctly closed on success or error (read: exception) in your logic.

Answer (score 0):

You will need another connection object. You can use use you connection if one command is all ready associate with it.

So what you can do is create another object of the command and use it.
Other wise change your logic as follows

crate an array while reading

```
   ArrayList ar=new ArrayList();
   while (sqldread.Read())
   {
        int Dbid = (int)sqldread["Id"];
        ar.add(Dbid); 
   }
```

Dispose the command
and use you update command using for loop on arraylist.

```
 for(int i=0;i<ar.length;i++)
 {
       //write update statement here.
 }
```